# Tensorflow serving SharedBatchScheduler for golang

Tags: tensorflow, go, tensorflow-serving

I want to optimize serving tensorflow model in Golang and study tensorflow serving.

[servers-with-multiple-models-model-versions-or-subtasks](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/batching#servers-with-multiple-models-model-versions-or-subtasks)

> SharedBatchScheduler presents an abstraction of queues, accepts requests to schedule a particular kind of task. Each batch contains tasks of just one type, i.e. from one queue. The scheduler ensures fairness by interleaving the different types of batches.

Is there any Golang repo working on SharedBatchScheduler? Or I have to rewrite the tensorflow serving [BatchingSession](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/96) C++ source code to Golang version?